# CheckBox does not update

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am using a CheckBox as a Toggle Button (checkBox.Appearance = Appearance.Button) in a child form. If the users presses the button a measurement cycle will start if some criteria are satisfied (e.g. temperature within range). The CheckBox.Checked property remains true until the measurement is completed.

If e.g. the temperature is out of range a warning will appear and the button will be reset. The same happens if the cycle ended properly. In the end this self-explaining function is called:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the button states to false
    /// </summary>
    public void ResetButton()
    {
        checkBox_Start.Checked = false;
    }
```

Now, when debugging, I see that the CheckBox_Start.Checked property is false and remains false. BUT the UI does not show the actual value. It seemingly remains checked. I have tried Refresh() and Update() on all levels.

Does anyone have an idea? What could possibly keep the UI from showing the actual value?

Comment: is it WebForms or WinForms?

Comment: try Application.DoEvents();

Comment: not clear from your question though, but if UI is not updating and if its a winforms project, then try doing your 'measurement cycle' on a separate thread i.e. (BackGround Worker process)

Comment: The measurement is running on a separate thread

Comment: May be you could be having cross thread references, accessing the UI element from another thread.

Comment: If there was a cross thread reference, there'd be an exception since I am accessing an UI element, wouldn't it?

Comment: There would be an exception, unless you turned it off using `Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem, except with DataGridView.  The solution I found was to invalidate the control and then request it to be redrawn, as follows:

```
public void ResetButton()
{
    checkBox_Start.Checked = false;
    checkBox_Start.Invalidate();
    checkBox_Start.Update();
}
```

Try that, see if it fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't whereas the Checked property is definitely false.

Comment: Hmm, odd.  Are you sure you're using the right checkbox?  Sounds silly, but it happens to the best of us.

Also check that you've not set it to treestate somewhere (checkBox.Threestate)

Comment: :D There are only two check boxes. Even I would not be able to mix them up. And yes: it is odd.

Comment: Something is quite wrong with that CheckBox. Even setting the Visible property to false does not work. That box just stays visible!!!

Comment: And when you change it from the Designer in the IDE?

Comment: @benJima Check you're not creating a new CheckBox somewhere, then.  Also, inspect the Controls property of the container while debugging.

Another simple check is to add an "OnClick" event through the designer, and to check the property values on the `sender` argument.

Comment: @Matthew Watson and RoadieRich: these were the hints in the right direction. Two days ago I had an issue after adding some Background Image to an element (can't remember which). But after that, the designer and the GUI turned out to be inconsistent and I had to add/remove stuff manually. I must have somehow messed up the CheckBox. I have just removed all of it in the designer and added it again in the IDE. And IT WORKS!! Love you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.MyCheckBox.Checked=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, after spending some times on CheckBox properties and methods, finally i realize that where I am initializing this control is not a suitable one. I was using a semi framework which in some cases doesnt goes in this code. I use this simple property:
 `checkBox_Start.Checked = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have InitializeComponent running twice.
That would cause the initial poster's control behaviour.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

This usually comes with trying to update UI within un-main thread. So I recommend to create a generic function doing UI update. And let the main or un-main thread call it if need to update UI.

This is my sample code:

```
    public void OnCheckBox(bool set_on) {
        if (set_on == true) {
            CBox.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                CBox.Checked = true;
                CBox.Invalidate();
                CBox.Update();
            }));
        }
        else {
            CBox.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                CBox.Checked = false;
                CBox.Invalidate();
                CBox.Update();
            }));
        }
    }
```

And you can call it like:

```
void run() {
    OnCheckBox(true);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    OnCheckBox(false);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    OnCheckBox(true);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    OnCheckBox(false);
}

Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run));
t.Start();
```